# How to redirect user after a callback of API EndPoint in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm creating a payment gateway in woocommerce. After sending a request to payment processor server and return Success as a status code. The server will send a GET request to an EndPoint of my own platform with some param indicating that an amount has been deducted from the user and the transaction has been successful .

Based on the (successful param) the user will be redirected to Thank You page.

I managed to create a simple API EndPoint but I'm stuck on how to respond to the Status Code and redirect the user to Thank You Page

```php
 add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'zaindob/v1', '/reqendpoint/' . 'statuscode=' . '(?P<statuscode>\d+)' , array(

    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'respondfun',
  ) );
} );

function respondfun(){


        $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
        wc_add_notice('Success = true' , 'Success' );           

        $order->payment_complete();      

        $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
        wp_redirect('https://iotkidsiq.com/thank-you');

}
```

After responding, the user won't be redirected. I'm sure my code is not right but i just want to show you what i have created so far

Answer (score 3):

you can add "exit;" after the wp_redirect() function. 
it will immediately stop further process for the rest api part.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use below code   


add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'add_form_data_into_custom_database' );
```

// API custom endpoints for WP-REST API

// http://localhost/wp-form/wp-json/custom-plugin/add/formdata

```
function add_form_data_into_custom_database() {

register_rest_route('custom-plugin', '/add/formdata', array(
        'methods'  => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'add_formdata',
    )
);


  }

function add_formdata($request) {

$create_id = $_POST['create_id']?$_POST['create_id']:"";
$create_name = $_POST['create_name'] ?$_POST['create_name']:"";
$create_email =$_POST['create_email'] ?$_POST['create_email']:"";

global $wpdb;       
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'userstable';
wp_handle_upload($_FILES["create_file"], array('test_form' => FALSE));

$wpdb->insert(
    $table_name, //table
    array('user_id' => $create_id,'name' => $create_name,'email' => $create_email), //data
    array('%s','%s') //data format          
);

wp_redirect( home_url() );
exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing redirect with `wp_redirect` and doing `exit` you could simply navigate the browser to perform redirect by returning status code `302` (or other 3xx code depending on your desired outcome. For more info visit [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections)) and specify `Location` header.

So, to do the redirect simply return the following:

```php
return rest_ensure_response(new WP_REST_Response(
  null,
  302,
  array(
    'Location' => get_home_url() // or set any other URL you wish to redirect to
  )
));
```